# Forking a repository in server using git path

Tags: android, git, git-fork

How can I fork a repository which is hosted in the server?  I have the .git path. 
I searched a lot and found out that it is possible in Gitlab, Github, Bitbucket using the options they have. But how can we fork it if it is stored in server using command line.

Comment: What do you mean by _I have the .git path_ ? The URL ending by _.git_ or the folder _.git_ ? What you have found ? Post links. Fork are just a clone of a repository with another remote repository URL where you can add changes.

Comment: Just use `git clone` ...providing whatever valid URI. Whatever you mean by "in the server"; this question does not even tell which "server" you are talking about; as Git by itself is no server. And also, this has absolutely nothing to with `android`.